# Jquery "Delay is Not A Function" with Jquery 1.6.4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked at some of the other questions on here pertaining to this problem but they were all using an older version of Jquery. I am having a problem with the latest version of jquery which I am grabbing from the goolge link:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

When I execute this code it is giving the error "delay is not a function". It didn't use to do this and I can't figure out why it might be doing it now.

```
$('.news_title_main').children('ul').delay(1500).slideUp(1000).queue(function(next) {
    removeLast();
});
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're loading the right jQuery version?

Comment: Ok, I see what is happening. I checked the Net tab in firebug and a widget is calling jquery 1.3.. ugh. Not sure how I can change this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `<head></head>` of your html page because that is where you usually put scripts such as javascript scripts.

Cheers!